# Why isn't my textured UV map showing?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to texture this 3D model of a squirrel, and I want to see how my eye placement looks on the model. I imported the textured UV map into blender (see the lower window), but it doesn't appear on the 3D model (see the upper window). How can I get my textured UV map to show up?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your viewport is set to texture view.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, such a simple fix! I'm completely new to blender, so thank you!!